# Twilio Ajax response always triggers 'Fail', Despite successfully making call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to make a simple Twilio application, I am broadly following this tutorial : https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-php
I have slightly tweaked and simplified it to suit my needs however, although the problem element doesn't seem any different.

Ajax :

```
$('#twilio_click_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // Prevent submit event from bubbling and automatically submitting the form
  e.preventDefault();
  // Call our ajax endpoint on the server to initialize the phone call
  $.ajax({
      url: '[...]/twilio_click_call',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          userPhone: $('#userPhone').val()
      }
  }).done(function(data) {
      // The JSON sent back from the server will contain a success message
      alert(data.message);
  }).fail(function(error) {
      alert('error');
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
public function twilio_click_call()
{
    $twilio_creds = array(
         'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' => 'xxxx',
         'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN' => 'xxxx',
         'TWILIO_NUMBER' => 'xxxx'
    );

    $userPhone = $this->input->post('userPhone');

    // Create authenticated REST client using account credentials
    $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client(
    $twilio_creds['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'],
    $twilio_creds['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
);

    try
    {
        $client->calls->create($userPhone, $twilio_creds['TWILIO_NUMBER'],
             array("url" =>  'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml')
        );
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
         // Failed calls will throw
         return $e;
    }

    return array('message' => 'Call incoming!');
}
```

The call initiate and runs through perfectly, however the Ajax response always triggers the .fail(), rather than the .done() method - cannot establish why.

Comment: What error appears on the alert?

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: Note: that response appears 1-2 seconds before my phone actually starts ringing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code. 
1. In ajax call you have defined the datType as json so it will expect the contentType too as json but you're returning the array that is first issue
2. You're calling url inside the url

Use this code:

```
public function twilio_click_call()
{
    $twilio_creds = array(
         'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' => 'xxxx',
         'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN' => 'xxxx',
         'TWILIO_NUMBER' => 'xxxx'
    );

    $userPhone = $this->input->post('userPhone');

    // Create authenticated REST client using account credentials
    $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client(
    $twilio_creds['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'],
    $twilio_creds['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
);

    try
    {
        $client->calls->create($userPhone, $twilio_creds['TWILIO_NUMBER'],
            array("url" =>  'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml')
        );
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
         // Failed calls will throw
         echo json_encode(array($e));
    }

    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Call incoming!'));
}
```

Comment: The double url call was a mistake when i copied the code and replaced the live url back with the test one, fixed.
And you're right json_encode would make sense, even though they don't do that in the official docs/tutorial.
Also it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Exactly as before : {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: It looks like your ajax call is not returning the data in json or json header is missed. This is working code and i have tested it. What framework are you using to return the data. Check how to return json header in the framework. Official documentation of ajax will provide description about the json dataType.. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests that have a callback placeholder, e.g. ?callback=?, are performed using JSONP unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Comment: I am using code igniter. And admittedly I didn't think about the header, as I haven't used the dataType property before in Ajax.
Tried setting the headers, however that still didn't solve it - on it's own, replacing the 'return' with an 'echo' as well, resolved the issue.

Comment: @LouisM. You need to use echo instead of the return. I have edited the answer.